# ember sass import file with tilde

Tags: ember.js, sass, ember-cli

I'm trying to `import` in an ember project that uses `ember-cli-sass` a `scss` file from a node_package which imports another scss file from another node package using `~`;

basically the file I'm importing contains the following instruction:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions"; // from bootstrap node_module
```

but that breaks the build since it seems that ember-cli is not resolving the `~`;

I've configured `ember-cli-build` with

```
sassOptions: {
  includePaths: [
    'node_modules/<package_name>/scss',
  ]
},
```

Comment: you could try [to use `node-sass`](https://github.com/simonexmachina/ember-cli-sass#using-a-different-sass-implementation).

Comment: I'm not sure if tilde is valid input in a path or sass input, but if it is this should probably be reported as a bug to ember-cli-sass.